# VisualVM Version of OpenJDK is not supported

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-17

I  have install VisualVM on my Ubuntu machine, and I'm getting this error when trying to open it:

`Version of OpenJDK is not supported. Please use the default-jdk.`

I have no idea on how to solve it

`java -version` outputs the following:

```
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: have you checked https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html ?  Try using the `--jdkhome` option

Comment: @user85421 yes. `$JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64` I've tried using `--jdkhome` as well

Comment: Check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Comment: Which version of VisualVM are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version I installed was the one published in APT. Apparently, it is not the official version. Official support solved my issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/558)